# Webpack with babel-loader does not recognize JSX code

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jsx

I'm having trouble getting a quite basic setup with webpack and babel working. I need babel to compile JSX, i don't use ES2015 features.

There are quite a few questions here on SO about this exact problem, but they all seem to be resolved by installing `babel-preset-react` or adding the preset option to babel in `webpack.config.js` all of which i have done already (I think).

I'm sure it's a simple thing I'm missing, but I just can't see it.

I extracted just the files needed to demonstrate my problem into [this gist](https://gist.github.com/powermosfet/ec204970e41a0026dd6e) (i used dashes in the filenames to indicate subfolders since you can't have folders in gists). My `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './app/js/app.js'
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: __dirname + '/app/js/',
        loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=react',
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + '/public'
  },
};
```

Note: in `package.json` everything is listed under 'dependencies', since i'm hosting this on heroku which does not install devdependencies (at least not by default)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it is worth, I am currently using webpack with latest babel with the following config line

```
{
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude:  /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
    loader: 'babel',
    query: {
        presets: ['react', 'es2015']
    }
}
```

Since you don't use es2015, you should be able to just leave the react preset in the list. Maybe `babel-loader?presets[]=react` is not working the way you expect it to.

Comment: This _did_ actually work for me too. It seems the important bit was your `exclude` option. I eventually got my `include` working too, by using path.resolve to build the path string.

Answer (score 1):

I banged my head against this for a long time as well.  It turned out that the `include` wasn't finding my directories.  The easiest way to fix, as pointed out in the comment to the marked answer above, is to use an exclude, e.g. `exclude: /node_modules/`, or whatever you need to exclude, and it'll start working.

If you're new to webpack, you'll find the error you get from the above kind of cryptic (will look like a parse error on your js, even though you thought babel should have transformed the JSX; the deal is that it didn't).